# C-type cable trying to make an OTG cable but only 3 wires - black, red, and blue

Tags: usb, connector, usb-c, otg

I have a C-type cable with only three wires. I took apart the cable to get a better look inside and I only have 3 solder points. I'm trying to make an OTG host of the C cable that I have. Where do I attach the 5.1 k resistor if I only have three solder points?

I'm trying to make C-type to micro USB.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

USB C cables with 3 wires are sometimes used with chargers. With this cable, you have VBUS, GND and CC.

The charger itself has the USB CC pullup resistor and monitors the CC voltage for other power profiles.

Your plan is converting this to an USB C plug to micro USB plug (data & power left to right). You would need to remove the CC wire from the PCB and wire it up via an 5.1K resistor to ground. Then wire VBUS and GND to the MicrUSB side. Then to connect the data identify the tiny D+ and D- pins of the USB C plug, and wire them to the microUSB connector

Answer (score 3):

If it is a connector assembly that is meant for charging, and if there are no pads for making it to be any other type of cable, then it is not be possible to repurpose this connector assembly to do what you want. Just buy the correct cable to begin with or a correct connector assembly which can do what you want to do.